# SwiftUI: keep data even after closing app

Tags: swift, swiftui

i have been trying to make that when a user adds a page to favorites or removes the page it saves it, so when a user closes the app it remembers it. I can't figure out how i can save the `mushrooms` table. I want to save it locally and is it done by using  `Prospects` ?

```
class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    public var mushrooms: Set<String>
    public let saveKey = "Favorites"
    
    init() {
        mushrooms = []
        
    }
    
    func contains(_ mushroom: Mushroom) -> Bool {
        mushrooms.contains(mushroom.id)
    }
    
    func add (_ mushroom: Mushroom) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        mushrooms.insert(mushroom.id)
        save()
    }
    
    func remove(_ mushroom: Mushroom) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        mushrooms.remove(mushroom.id)
        save()
    }
    
    func save() {
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You could save it to a file as json

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Hey, thanks for commenting and i was able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Here is the code i did if someone else is struggling with this.
I added this to the `save` function

```
func save() {
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
   if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(mushrooms)  {
   defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "Favorites")
   }
}
```

And to the `init()` :

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  if let data = defaults.data(forKey: "Favorites") {
  let mushroomData = try? decoder.decode(Set<String>.self, from: data)
   self.mushrooms = mushroomData ?? []
   } else {
   self.mushrooms = []
 }
```

EDIT:
and of course add the defaults

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
```